# How to align submit button to right of dropdown HTML Bootstrap 5 using DIV's and labels

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-5

I apologize if this has been asked before. I searched but couldn't find my simple scenario. How can I position the Submit button to the right of the Countries dropdown? It is to the right now, but it is on the same line as the labels, and I would like it positioned to the right of the Countries dropdown.

```
<div class="container border">
    <div class="col-12 p-3">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="form-label">Continent</label>
                    <select class="form-control" asp-for="ContinentId" asp-items="Model.Continents">
                        <option value="">Select Continent</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="form-label">Country</label>
                    <select class="form-control" asp-for="CountryId"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ">Display Airports</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, I have tried changing the div layout and tried all the closely related questions I could find. If I have missed a question that answers this, please point me to it.